# How to Query the room database and get the result as per the need instantly?

Tags: android, database, android-room

I have a **Query** that returns the **boolean** value when certain condition is meet .This value is use in **adapter** ,**service** and other **classes** too.The **Aysnc** task do not have a return type.So how can i make a proper query to Database and get the result .  I have also made the **repository** class and i would like to use this if its possible .

There is one condition here that you should **not** use the **query** on **main** **thread** as per google architecture guidelines

I dont want this value to trigger  any other functions if the value is changed . I only want to query it whenever i want and get the result to the method .

The **next problem** i am facing is I **cant** **call view model** in any   **methods** that are there  in **service** and **adapters**. I want to **insert** data or **delete** data when app is in **background** using **service** and also want to **update** the **list** with condition that is used in **adapter**.

I am trying to explore the room database .So guide me to achieve the best results.

Comment: Room database returns Observables, no need to use any AsynkTask

Comment: @KonstantinVolkov Can you please share the documentation i can follow .

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article about Room Rx approach 
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757

The point is to return not an object but Observable (Maybe in this example) from Room

```
@Query(“SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = :userId”)
Maybe<User> getUserById(String userId);
```

Then you can fetch the data in a separated thread without using any AsynTask

```
mDatabase.userDao()
  .getUserById(USER.getId())
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(user -> doSomethigWithUser(user));



private void doSomethigWithUser(User user) {
.....
}
```

Comment: If I do that I get a `The result of subscribe is not used` warning. What should be done in this case? Can I safely ignore that warning?